# .NET Core equivalent for System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.IsHosted

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there an equivalent for `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.IsHosted`? The `IWebHostEnvironment` does not contain that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a .NET Core equivalent for `HostingEnvironment.IsHosted`. You can read more about it on the following GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7400), which also contains some alternatives/workarounds.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I used `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGenerator` that did the magic.